# Mysql Event Update and search

Tags: mysql

I have a demo database where I need to set the status back to 0 each night in any table where userid = '1'

Is it possible to do that in the mySql event scheduler? Or do I need to specify each query individually?

So for example: Update "table" set status='0' where userid='1'.

Comment: This is what I have now:


DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT updatedemouser1
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2012-04-26 02:00:41'
  COMMENT 'This is for updating all demo data'
  DO
    BEGIN
          Update table1 set status='0' where userid='1';
          Update table2 set orderqty='25';
          Update table3 set status='0' where userid='1';
          Update table4 set status='0' where userid='1';
          Update table5 set status='0' where userid='1';
          Update table6 set active='0' where userid='1';
    END|

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Are you really using string types to store integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think your currently method is the most sensible.  But some other options might include:

- a multi-table `UPDATE`, however you'd still have to explicitly name each table - so I'm not sure it gains you much (except perhaps a little obfuscation) and it'll almost certainly have worse performance from performing the joins:

  ```
  UPDATE
  FROM
         table1
    JOIN table2 USING (userid)
    JOIN table3 USING (userid)
    JOIN table4 USING (userid)
    JOIN table5 USING (userid)
  SET
    table1.status = '0',
    table2.status = '0',
    table3.status = '0',
    table4.status = '0',
    table5.status = '0'
  WHERE userid = '1';
  ```
- dynamically constructing your current series of `UPDATE` queries using prepared statements - but unless you are frequently changing the number or names of your tables, I don't really see the point:

  ```
  SET @qry = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        "UPDATE `",
        REPLACE(table_name, "`", "``"), -- in case you have strange table names
        "` SET status='0' WHERE userid='1';"
    )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  );

  PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go ahead and keep it with the named table version per your suggestions. The code you gave is great, so thanks for that! I'll test on speed etc..and see if it gains much, but the ideas are awesome.